# Playing sounds over Hangouts with SoundJS

Tags: html5-audio, soundjs, google-hangouts

I want to be able to play a sound via button click and have it 'broadcast' to everyone in my Google Hangout.

I don't care about live microphone streams or anything else. Just click a button, play a sound that everyone can hear. Most sounds are between 1 and 8 seconds. It would be nice If a sound could loop as well. I'm using SoundJS to achieve this on the web so I'd like to continue using that framework.

I've searched this topic many times but it seems that Google Hangouts documentation is a little sparse. I'd love to see a sample audio app that does something like this.

Thanks!